# Proving that the tensor product is generated by $a\otimes b$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If we let $A$ be a right R module and B a left R module then we define $A\otimes _RB$ to be a $\mathbb{Z}$-module along with a middle linear map $f:A\times B\rightarrow A\otimes B$ such that if there is another middle linear map $g:A\times B\rightarrow $ C for some $\mathbb{Z}$-module $C$ then we have a unique $h:A\otimes _RB\rightarrow C$ such that $fh=g$

I am trying to show that the tensor product as defined above is generated by the elements of the form $a\otimes b$.

What I have done is suppose not. Then let $C=A\otimes _R C$ and the map $g=f$. Then clearly one choice of $h$ is the identity map.

Now I claim that we could also define another map $h':A\otimes _RB\rightarrow A\otimes _RB$ such that $h$ is the identity on elements of the form $a\otimes b$ and $0$ on everything else. Clearly this satisfies the condition $fh=f$ but I am unsure if this is infact a $\mathbb{Z}$ linear map

Comment: I assume that $a \otimes b$ in this context means $f(a,b)$. You can't define $h$ by just sending those elements to itself and the rest to $0$, because you'd run into problems with $(a \otimes b) + (a' \otimes b')$. What you can do, I think, is map the submodule generated by all the $a \otimes b$ to itself and the rest to $0$. I didn't check details, though.

Comment: @Magdiragdag yes sorry that is what I meant, the stuff generated by  the tensors $a\otimes b$. I think there is a problem with this approach though. Say we let $K$ be the module generated by stuff of the form $a\otimes b$. Then take $x,y\in A\otimes B-K$. Then I see no reason as to why we couldn't have $x+y\in K$ and $x+y\neq 0$ which would be a problem for the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather let $C$ be the submodule of $A\otimes B$ that is generated by the $a\otimes b$.
Then $(a,b)\mapsto a\otimes b$ defines a map $g\colon A\times B\to C$. If we append the inclusion $\iota\colon C\to A\otimes B$, we obtain the canonical map $A\times B\to A\otimes B$, which is middle linear, hence $g$ is already middle linear.
Hence there exists a unique linear $h\colon A\otimes B\to C$ with $h\circ f=g$.
Consider $\iota\circ h$. It is a linear map $A\otimes B\to A\otimes B$ such that $(\iota\circ h)\circ f=f$. As also $\operatorname{id}_{A\otimes B}\circ f=f$, we have $\iota\circ h=\operatorname{id}_{A\otimes B}$. Similarly show $h\circ\iota=\operatorname{id}_C$. So $\iota$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Let $h:A\otimes_{R}B\rightarrow D$ be a (abelian) grouphomomorphism
and define $g:A\times B\rightarrow D$ by $\left(a,b\right)\mapsto h\left(a\otimes b\right)$.

Then $g$ is biadditive so a unique (abelian) grouphomomorphism $\hat{g}:A\otimes_{R}B\rightarrow D$
exists with $g\left(a,b\right)=\hat{g}\left(a\otimes b\right)$, hence $h\left(a\otimes b\right)=\hat{g}\left(a\otimes b\right)$.

The
uniqueness tells us that $\hat{g}$ and $h$ coincide. So apparantly
the values of $h$ on elements $a\otimes b$ determine $h$. This is true for any such $h$. This
implies that the elements $a\otimes b$ must generate $A\otimes_{R}B$.